# Prevent Sound from Entering Mattress through Bed Legs

Tags: sound-proofing, bedroom

There is a construction site next to my bed room and especially low frequency sounds resulting from heavy machines and vehicles enter my bed through its four legs. As I am a side-sleeper the vibrations end up on my ear through the mattress.

What would be a reasonable construction of layers or materials that I could shove under each of the four legs to prevent sounds from being lead into the bed?

Comment: Anything very soft, really. Folded towels might do the trick. However, you might find that the sound isn't coming through the bed legs at all. Low-frequency sound moves a lot of air, even through walls.

Comment: The kind of sound I'm trying to absorb is rather mid-frequency sound from stomping, running, jumping, bumping etc. travelling via the floor.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's practical to come up with a definitive answer without experimentation, but I would try these:

- sheets of rubber, such as what is sold in the plumbing section of the hardware store, maybe folded over a couple times
- [sound isolating feet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JBLFWQ) sold for washers/dryers

Comment: Rubber / foam would be the common wisdom approach. But otoh it seems that mass is what absorbes sound. So iron or stone / concrete slabs would be more effective I'd assume.

Answer (score 1):

Mass absorbes sound. As I haven't been using my larger dumbbell plates in a while I'm using them now as a layer between floor and bed legs - 10kg each. It's hard to say how much it actually improves the situation but I can confirm that it does improve sound insulation at least somewhat. Recommended for people sleeping in ear-on-mattress positions.